# How to send multiple emails from sql server database using sp_send_dbmail procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-send-dbmail

I have procedure which results a data table contains 3 columns Emails,proposal_Type,count(MatchestoEmail) the matches is based on proposal_type.
Now I have to send a notification mails to the 'Emails' stating that they have these many number of matches based on Proposal_Type. the procedure output data will be like this.

```
Emails           Prop_Type   Matches

abc@gmail.com     1            3 

abc@gmail.com     2            4

def@gmail.com     3            2
```

I want the mails to be recipient and the remaining two columns to in the Body of the Email with some additional text. plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is an educative question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited

This should work

```
create proc [dbo].[SendProposalReport] as   
declare rscursor cursor read_only
for 
select Emails, Prop_Type, count(Matches) as Matches  from proposals
group by Emails, Prop_Type

    declare @Emails            nvarchar (100)
    declare @Prop_Type    int
    declare @Maches    int

open rscursor
fetch next from rscursor into @Emails,@Prop_Type,@Maches
while @@fetch_status=0
    begin

         EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = @Emails,
        @subject = 'Example Email',
        @body = 'write your message here',
        @profile_name = 'ExampleProfile',

        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1        

    fetch next from rscursor into @Emails,@Prop_Type,@Maches
end
close rscursor
deallocate rscursor
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what i am looking for.

Comment: @Raj, Can you give more explanation, it will help if you provide some code samples of what you have

Comment: EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    recipients = 'Emails of resulted data table',
    subject = 'Example Email',
    body = 'The other two columns of data table',
    profile_name = 'ExampleProfile' etc

Comment: the @recipients have to be from the my procedure resulted data          i.e   @recipients='Emails column'  and @body='other two columns of Result'

Answer (score 2):

A cursor would solve your problem:

```
DECLARE <yourvariables>
DECLARE emailCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT emails, prop_type, matches FROM <yourtable>
OPEN emailCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO @email, @prop_type, @matches
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @BODY = '<body text>' + @prop_type + '<more text>' + @matches
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @recipients = @email,
   @subject = '<subject>',
   @body = @BODY
   FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO @email, @prop_type, @matches
END
CLOSE emailCursor
DEALLOCATE emailCursor
```