# Create stored procedure for setting reminder for document created

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I want to create a stored procedure for the documents whose `NStatusFlag` should not be equal to `5` and `14`

And also it should send Reminder to the respective user if the Document is with them for more than 3 days and if it is for more than 5 days then it should send it to its senior.

The date should be calculated with the `U_datetime` of the table and with the `SYSTEM` date from the system.

My `NStatusFlag` suggest which all documents are opened.

I tried below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT
AS
BEGIN
    Select * from inward_doc_tracking_trl 
        where NStatus_flag <> 5
        and NStatus_flag <> 14
END
GO
```

So I got all the documents which are opened, like below

[image]

But I am stuck how to get the all user by comparing with the date and send the reminders.

Also, I will get the Name of the USer with which the document is assigned from the `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table.

**NOTE**

`inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table `mkey` is related to `ref_mkey` from the `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table.

**UPDATE**

I get all the User from this query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT
AS
BEGIN
    
    Select distinct a.mkey, b.mkey, a.first_name + ' ' + a.last_name from user_mst a
    inner join inward_doc_tracking_hdr b 
    on a.mkey = b.User_Id
END
GO
```

**UPDATE to get Senior name**

```
select * from inward_doc_tracking_hdr order by mkey desc  -- here I get To_User
  select * from user_mst where mkey = 187         -- here I get To_User
 select Reporting_To,* from emp_mst where mkey = 122 -- here I get Senior
```

Comment: To get the user you need to use a join and join to the user table. To get the records with correct dates you need to use a `where` on the date field. You need to compare that with the current date, (using the function `getdate()`) and you need to use the `dateadd` function on that to move back x days

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thanks for the logic. It would be great if you post the _solution_ for it. Also let me know if you want anything from me.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: See my update that which I tried. Now I am getting stucked at how to get the `Nstatus_flag` which is coming from `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table which respective conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the tracking lines of people with documents for 3 days or more (you might need to be careful with the time component). Please test and see if this gets what you want.

```
    Select TL.*
    from inward_doc_tracking_trl TL
    where TL.NStatus_flag NOT IN (5,14)
    and TL.U_datetime <= DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())
```

This query then works out if its 3 or 5 days overdue and populates a second column if it's 3 days overdue:

```
    Select 
    TL.*, 
    U.UserName,
    CASE 
    WHEN TL.U_datetime <= DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE()) 
    THEN M.Reporting_To
    ELSE NULL 
    END SeniorName
    from inward_doc_tracking_trl TL
    INNER JOIN inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH
    ON TH.mkey = TL.ref_mkey
    INNER JOIN user_mst U
    ON TH.User_Id = U.mkey
    INNER JOIN emp_mst M
    ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey
    where TL.NStatus_flag NOT IN (5,14)
    and TL.U_datetime <= DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())
```

You need to run that every day, I suggest inside a scheduled SQL Agent Job

With regards to 'sending a reminder', then assuming this is email, I suggest you first set up SQL Mail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh245116.aspx

Then use `sp_send_dbmail` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190307.aspx to send the email message

You'll also need to use the above query in a cursor and feed that into your `sp_send_dbmail` [How to send multiple emails from sql server database using sp_send_dbmail procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194804/how-to-send-multiple-emails-from-sql-server-database-using-sp-send-dbmail-proced)

Have a crack at that and ask more questions if you like

Comment: my username comes from `user_mst` table and has relation with `UserId`.to `mkey` from `user_mst` As I tried your second code, it is giving error as `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` Also Yes this will be a scheduler which will be running everyday

Comment: It's hard to know why the error is appearing. I suggest that you selectively remove bits of code to find the line with the error. Alternatively you can double click the error and it usually jumps to somewhere near the error. These things are easier to do if you set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Does `user_mst` join to `inward_doc_tracking_trl` or `inward_doc_tracking_trh`? As you can see I'm just guessing a whole load of stuff here. Is the senior user also in the `user_mst` table? Is it on the same record? usually these tables join back to themselves.

Comment: `user_mst` join to `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` relating as `User_Id` of hdr to `mkey` of `user_mst`

Comment: Also the senior comes from the `emp_mst` table as column name as `Reporting_To`

Comment: and how does the emp_mst table join to the other three tables? This might take a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115797/discussion-between-n-k-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: chat window is not opening at my side. I will explain u here

Comment: See from `inward_doc_tracking_hdr`  I get `To_User` which gives me the name of the employee from the `User_mst` and `User_mst` `employee_mkey` gives me Senior name. Here are the queries  **select * from inward_doc_tracking_hdr order by mkey desc  -- here I get To_User
select * from user_mst where mkey = 187         -- here I get To_User
select Reporting_To,* from emp_mst where mkey = 122 -- here I get Senior**

Comment: I;ve taken a guess at the relationships and altered the query

Comment: looking some what OK, tried and getting as `The multi-part identifier "E.Reporting_To" could not be bound.` at `Select 
    TL.*, `

Comment: Oh sorry it's hard to code without the tables. Check the edit

Comment: yes, now it ran fine. You were telling something about `cursor` to loop for every user? how to use cursor here ?

Comment: i will use the procedure in the front end for mailing functionality. I want just the cursor part now. For looping every user.

Comment: I did link to an article on using a cursor to loop around a query and send emails from it. I suggest you read that and ask a new question, otherwise I'll be here all night. Sorry I can't help further - good luck.